# i need similar query without insert (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I need a query selected all month like this

```
DECLARE @ano TABLE (
mes int
)
insert @ano (mes) values (1)
insert @ano (mes) values (2)
insert @ano (mes) values (3)
insert @ano (mes) values (4)
insert @ano (mes) values (5)
insert @ano (mes) values (6)
insert @ano (mes) values (7)
insert @ano (mes) values (8)
insert @ano (mes) values (9)
insert @ano (mes) values (10)
insert @ano (mes) values (11)
insert @ano (mes) values (12)
select * from @ano
```

but the program that i'm using accepts no inserts... D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would get you the same result:

```
SELECT 1 AS mes
UNION
SELECT 2 
UNION
SELECT 3 
UNION
SELECT 4 
UNION
SELECT 5 
UNION
SELECT 6 
UNION
SELECT 7 
UNION
SELECT 8 
UNION
SELECT 9 
UNION
SELECT 10 
UNION
SELECT 11 
UNION
SELECT 12
```

But it's not particularly elegant.

Comment: You'd only need the as mes on the first select

Comment: Thanks, edited accordingly - you learn something every day! :)

Comment: Yeah, i know =(, but the program that i'm using is a shit... It works, thanks.

Comment: @LuizCarlosCoelho if an answer solves your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: Just a note: Using the recursive CTE and understanding how ti works can help you build experience for more complex tasks. It is usually better to spend a minute or two for a more elegant and re-usable solution.

Comment: @rpd I definitely agree, which is why I upvoted [Zohar Peled](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3094533/zohar-peled)'s answer.

Comment: it's more "elegant" but does not work with me, "syntax error" and i dunno why

Comment: Perhaps the application you're using to run these SQL statements doesn't just pass them straight to the SQL Server and for some reason cannot handle a CTE - what application are you using? Alternatively, did you not add `SELECT * FROM ano` after the declaration of the CTE? Without explicitly running a `SELECT` to return results from the CTE, I also get an error in SSMS - `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Answer (score 7):

If you need a 12 numbers table for only a single query you can use a recursive cte:

```
;WITH ano as
(
    select 1 as mes
    union all 
    select mes + 1
    from ano
    where mes < 12
)
Select mes from ano
```

Another option is to use the `values` clause, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES
    (1), 
    (2), 
    (3), 
    (4), 
    (5), 
    (6), 
    (7), 
    (8), 
    (9), 
    (10), 
    (11), 
    (12)
) ano(mes)
```

Comment: Would it be worth appending a `SELECT` after the declaration of the CTE? If I just run the code as is from the answer in SSMS, I get a syntax error: `Incorrect syntax near ')'.` Only when I append something like `SELECT * FROM ano` do I actually see results displayed without an error.